# Filter by true-false-Attributes 1-N relationship

Tags: mysql

I am working on a MySQL-Project right now and want to do the following:
I got the Tables `Meals`, `Ingredients` and `Meals_Ingredients` and I am fetching data from them with the following query:

```
SELECT m.Available
     , m.ID
     , m.Name
     , i.Vegetarian
     , i.Vegan    
  FROM Meals m   
  LEFT  
  JOIN Meals_Ingredients mi
    ON mi.MealID = m.ID  
  LEFT    
  JOIN Ingredients i
    ON i.ID =  mi.IngredientID 
 ORDER 
    BY m.ID;
```

The query returns the following table (don't mind the Names, it is all in German):

[image]

My goal is to make two new queries, that show only `Vegan` or only `Vegetarian` meals, e.g. all Ingredients are Vegan or Vegetarian respectively. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by meal you can set a condition in the HAVING clause like:

```
SELECT m.Available, m.ID, m.Name 
FROM Meals m
LEFT JOIN Meals_Ingredients mi ON mi.MealID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN Ingredients i ON i.ID =  mi.IngredientID
GROUP BY m.Available, m.ID, m.Name
HAVING SUM(i.Vegetarians = 0) = 0
```

This will return all meals that do not have `Vegeterians = 0` meaning they are only  *Vegeterians*.
Change the condition to:

```
HAVING SUM(i.Vegan = 0) = 0
```

for meals that are only *Vegan*.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the meals whose all ingredients are vegan, you could filter with a correlated subquery in a `not exists` condition, as follows:

```
select m.*
from meals m
where not exists (
    select 1
    from meals_ingredients mi
    inner join ingredients i on i.id = mi.ingredient_id
    where mi.meal_id = m.id and i.vegan = 0
)
```

This phrases as: pull out all meals that do not have an ingredient that is not vegan.

For vegetarian meals, you would change condition `i.vegan = 0` to `i.vegetarian = 0`.